# OAuth 2.0, Swagger and DotNet Core

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to allow me to use OAuth 2.0, and writing a DotNet Core API application, which all works fine and Auth0 provide a nice example to use.

I am however having trouble getting Swagger to authorise, anyone managed this and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I had a similar situation, my project is done in net core 3 also using Auth0 and implementing Swagger. My code in **Startup.cs** looks like this.

```
        //Swagger
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            // Another options like docs info or xml

            c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme.
                                Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                                Example: Bearer adsdflEDc.asdkjhd.aEASDAD",
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Scheme = "Bearer"
            });

            c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
            {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                            Id = "Bearer"
                        },
                        Scheme = "oauth2",
                        Name = "Bearer",
                        In = ParameterLocation.Header
                    },
                    new List<string>()
                }
            });
        });
```

You just need to add the **AddSecurityDefinition** and **AddSecurityRequirement** options,  when you run your API you can see in Swagger UI a button in the top right and when you click you will see that it asks for the authorization token, which will be applied to all protected endpoints.

[image]